# Jquery div movement on timer then repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some issues with some code. I am trying to get a div to move in time with a slider show. Each time a new slide is shown the div moves. 
This is what I came up with

```
setInterval(function() { 
$( ".bar" ).animate({ "left": "+=13.5em" }, "slow" );
},  3000);
```

This works great, the div keeps up with the slider. But It never stops. I have been trying to come up with the code to make this work but I can't seem to do it.

Once the div reaches a certain point I want it to go back to its starting point and then repet its animation over and over just as the image slider does.

Could I put another timer on another line of code to tell the div to go back to a  point after a set duration? then the above code will keep playing the aniamtion? (I will give this ago now!)

Comment: Why not just set a condition to check the current position of the `.bar` every time the function runs and if it's past the point that you want it to be, reset the position to the starting point?

Answer (score 0):

```
var startPos = $(".bar").offset();
var endPos = $("foo").offset();   
var foo = setInterval(function() { 
      var updatedPos = $( ".bar" ).position();
      if (updatedPos.left === endPos.left) {
           $(".bar").css({"left":startPos.left,"top":startPos.top});
      }
      $( ".bar" ).animate({ "left": "+=13.5em" }, "slow" );
},  3000);
```

EDIT:
    `var pos = $(".bar").offset();`   this gets the position relative to the document, you could also get the position relative to the parent node with `.position()` and then check on the interval if it hit the position, you could also just update the left right or top bottom, depending on your needs. but this would be a way to reset the position. You just need to know the start and end points.

Comment: This doesn't help him reset it to the original position

Comment: edited to answer the question in regards to resetting the position

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plugin for the slider? Some plugins you can set a callback like flexslider plugin:

```
$(elem).flexslider({
    before: function(){
        //event before slide transition
    },
    after: function(){
        //event after slide transition
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = $(".bar").length;
var current = 1;    
setInterval(function() { 
    $( ".bar" ).animate({ "left": "+=13.5em" }, "slow" );
    current++;
    if(current == count) {
        $( ".bar" ).animate({ "right": "+=" + (count*13.5) "em" }, "fast" );
        current = 1;
    }
},  3000);
```

Maybe something like that?